# android database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-sqlite

in my application i get this error and i'm try to resolve that. but i can not do that.

```
Cursor c = G.db.getReceivedFromDatabaseByCount ( username, received_count );
if (c != null && c.moveToLast () && c.getCount () != 0) {
        for (int i = cursor_count; i > 0; i--) {
          ...
          c.moveToPrevious ();
        }
    }
c.close ();
```

after any search in google and this site and adding `c.moveToLast ()` to `if` this problem must be resolve.

Full LogCat Result:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample/com.sample.Service.ServiceDialog}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 4
    ...
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 4
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at com.sample.Service.ServiceDialog.updateAndIntertDialog(ServiceDialog.java:216)
    at com.sample.Service.ServiceDialog.onCreate(ServiceDialog.java:125)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
    ... 11 more
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 4
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at com.sample.Service.ServiceDialog.updateAndIntertDialog(ServiceDialog.java:216)
    at com.sample.Service.ServiceDialog.onCreate(ServiceDialog.java:125)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not set `int i = cursor_count` as its equivalent to cursor's length, which is not the same as last index value.

It should be like:

```
for (int i = (cursor_count - 1); i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: dont resolve problem now i get this error:  `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 50`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though you don't want that `for` loop in there at all. You just move to the last one, as you're doing, and then keep consuming records and invoking `c.moveToPrevious()` until you run out of records.